# How can I deduplicate identifier rows in Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, duplicates

I have data that looks like this:

```
id     | neighbour_id | distance_meters  
-----------+--------------+------------------
6426 |    6428 | 287.488739674119
6429 |    6428 | 249.869885094284
6428 |    6429 | 249.869885094272
8666 |    8667 | 234.957790871716
6427 |    6430 | 231.043072328645
6431 |    6430 | 206.299209322371
...etc
```

It's the result of a query to my postgres table that calculates distance between objects with a **unique** `id`, and tells me the closest one as the `neighbour_id` (how this occurs not important). The `neighbour_id` column is not unique.

This is a de-duplication task because those objects within 300m of one another I want to consider part of the same structure.

How in PostgreSQL can I create a new column for this table called `structure_id` which can group the objects by their neighbour associations?

For example, ids 6426, 6429 and 6428 are part of the same structure and should share a structure_id of say 6426 (or 6429 or 6428, which one unimportant, so long as they are the same). There should also be a single structure_id for ids 6427, 6430 and 6431 (based on this data snippet).

Comment: And what would you do if there were a chain a-b-c-d-e-f where each were 200 meters apart from the "neighbor" but further from the others?

Comment: This is the DB-version of an eigenvector (or clustering) problem. Unsolvable in pure SQL; must be solved iteratively. I'd start by a union-find like structure.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Those would be part of the same structure too